# Javascript window.onload issue in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am going to popup a "Term of Usage" modal dialog when the user first opens a SharePoint site. I am using the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()` function. It is created in the SharePoint **Content editor** Web Part.

When I first open the page, the Modal dialog works fine. However, it does not work if I open the page again. Could anyone help me on how to solve this problem? It seems like a caching issue?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        alert('ok');
        var options = {

            url: 'http://www.google.com',
            Title: "Survey",

            height: 500

        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your JavaScript - after all, you've seen it work.  Have you tried clearing your cache to get it to work again?  You may also want to ensure that SharePoint hasn't "helpfully" modified your code.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `window.onload = codeAddress`, use:

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("codeAddress");`

and SharePoint will call your function at window load. `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` itself is a SharePoint object.

I had this issue, and came across [this link](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2007/12/16/WSS-Tip-_2300_19_3A00_-Using-JavaScript-in-Body-OnLoad-Event.aspx), which explains the reason;

> When developing web parts or other controls that use JavaScript, it's quite common to need to call some function on the Body OnLoad event of the web page. The problem with this is that, in SharePoint, the Body element is in the master page and not in the control, so doing this is can be tricky.
>
> Fortunately, the SharePoint team gave the developers a way to do this easily, using a special array called **_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames**. The only thing you have to do is push your function's name to this array and it will get called in the OnLoad event of the window.